# angular-material and cordova : poor animation performance on android

Tags: cordova, css-animations, angular-material, hardware-acceleration

Any suggestions to make cordova + angular-material app run animations faster and smoother on android ? Even on latest build of angular-material, animate is too bad on android devices.

Comment: I've encountered this problem too. Couldn't find a real solution yet :/

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this answer after months because i see lots of people are still facing this issue.

I found a work around for this problem. Adding css hardware acceleration to specific class of angular-material directives where you are getting poor animation solves the issue.

Following is testing on Moto E, Moto G, One plus 1 and One plus 2 android phones for poor sidenav animation and works smooth.

Add following code to your custom css file and link it after angular-material.css

[image]

```
md-sidenav.md-closed-add, md-sidenav.md-closed-remove {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -moz-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -o-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  transform: translateX(0) !important;

  -moz-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -o-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;

  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in all !important; }

md-sidenav.md-closed-add.md-closed-add-active, md-sidenav.md-closed-remove.md-closed-remove-active {
  -moz-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -o-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  transform: translateX(0) !important;

  -moz-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -o-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;

  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1) !important;
}

.md-sidenav-left, md-sidenav {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -moz-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -o-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  transform: translateX(0) !important;

  -moz-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -o-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;

  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
}

.md-sidenav-left.md-closed, md-sidenav.md-closed {
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%)!important;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%)!important;
  -o-transform: translateX(-100%)!important;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%)!important;
  transform: translateX(-100%)!important;

  -moz-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%)!important;
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%)!important;
  -o-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%)!important;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%)!important;
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%)!important;

  -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)!important;
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)!important;
  -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)!important;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)!important;
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)!important;
}

md-sidenav.md-locked-open-add, md-sidenav.md-locked-open-remove {
  -moz-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -o-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  transform: translateX(0) !important;

  -moz-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -o-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;

  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
}

md-sidenav.md-locked-open, md-sidenav.md-locked-open.md-closed, md-sidenav.md-locked-open.md-closed.md-sidenav-left, md-sidenav.md-locked-open.md-closed, md-sidenav.md-locked-open.md-closed.md-sidenav-right, md-sidenav.md-locked-open-remove.md-closed {
  -moz-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -o-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  transform: translateX(0) !important;

  -moz-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -o-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;

  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
}
md-sidenav.md-closed.md-locked-open-add {
  -moz-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -o-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  transform: translateX(0) !important;

  -moz-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -o-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;

  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
}
md-sidenav.md-closed.md-locked-open-add-active {
  -moz-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -o-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  transform: translateX(0) !important;

  -moz-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -o-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;

  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
}

.md-sidenav-backdrop.md-locked-open {
  display: none;
  -moz-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -o-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  transform: translateX(0) !important;

  -moz-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -o-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;

  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
}

.md-sidenav-left, md-sidenav {
  -moz-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -o-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  transform: translateX(0) !important;

  -moz-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -o-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0) !important;

  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
}

.md-sidenav-left.md-closed, md-sidenav.md-closed {
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%)!important;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%)!important;
  -o-transform: translateX(-100%)!important;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%)!important;
  transform: translateX(-100%)!important;

  -moz-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%)!important;
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%)!important;
  -o-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%)!important;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%)!important;
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%)!important;

  -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)!important;
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)!important;
  -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)!important;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)!important;
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)!important;
}
```